# What happens to webpages when you copy HTML source code into a .html file in notepad?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

So I am just starting out trying to familiarize myself with some HTML, and for lack of knowledge of better places to start, I have been looking at some source code taken from websites and copy and pasting them into a notepad and then running the html file. But when I do this I often get incomplete pages with no links working(for example stackoverflow website). Is this because I don't have the images saved on my website, or because there are CSS and javascript pages that are hidden, or what other reason?

Why do simpler webpages (say http://sheldonbrown.com/web_sample1.html) look mostly complete when i do this, but more complicated/bigger websites have this problem?

Also if anyone has a good alternative to learning HTML that would also be appreciated.

Thanks

Just to add onto this question, is there something wrong with writing html in a notepad? I noticed that even if i have a text file that says "hello" and nothing else, running it as a html file will show hello, should this happen? Also, it seems to ignore my conditional statements say I do 
 i am not ie 
the "i am not ie" message still appears in all browsers (IE included). Why is this the case as well?

Comment: You're probably only grabbing the HTML and not any linked resources like images, stylesheets, and scripts. Even if you do download all the assets for a page, you'd need to make sure the links to them are fixed to properly point to them.

Comment: I just edited my answer to address your 2nd question.

Comment: Writing in notepad is not a problem. All you need is a editor which returns plain text. Ei Word isnt plain text, it has styling and format in it. Even though Notepad itself is fine, a lot of programmers prever syntaxt highlighting (google that term), so I recommend Scite or Notepad++. Works about the same, but because of the hjghlighing you'll notice errors way faster (thus saving precious internet time)

Answer (score 2):

Say I have a very tiny webpage, `http://www.my-tiny-page.com`:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="/images/example.jpg" >
  </body>
</html>
```

You look at the source, simple enough, and copy it to your notepad, and open it.
**HEY! The image is not loading?!**

The reason for this is really simple actually. The tiny-website links to the image **`relatively`**, which means they don't add the full domainname to it (= a lot easier).

Relative means "look from the directory where I am", or when starting with a slash it means "look from the extention (also know as document root)".

If you change the images to **the full url**, it'll work again:
`http://www.my-tiny-page.com/images/example.jpg`

---

How about styling and javascript? Exact same principle.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply, can i add another question though?

Comment: If it's a small one yes, You can edit your topic and add it to it

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working is because the HTML only contains the basic structure and content of the site. Images are almost always linked relative to the root directory, meaning your browser is not going to be able to find them unless you saved the images in the same folder structure as the website. Without the CSS files(styling), Javascript files(functionality), images, etc. it's not going to look anything like the page where you're getting the code from.

Also, chances are the code you are seeing could have been generated by PHP, either way, it's probably too advanced for someone just starting out.

My suggestion would be to take an online course, there are several beginner HTML/CSS courses available. I was a big fan of [Code School](https://www.codeschool.com/) when I first started out.

Learn the basics of HTML first(html/body tags, headers, divs, etc.) before moving on to more advanced stuff.

**To address your additional question:**

No. There is nothing wrong with using notepad to write HTML, in fact, back in 2004 when I first started, that is exactly what I used. However, we have come a long way since then. There are now text editors that can predict what you are trying to do as well as color code your tags to make it easier to debug. While there's nothing wrong with using Notepad, I would STRONGLY suggest using something like [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) instead, it will make your life much easier.

Here is what a proper conditional statement to target only IE would look like:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    Only IE browsers can see this.
<![endif]-->
```

You can also target specific versions of IE. That would look like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    Only IE7 or lower browsers can see this.
<![endif]-->
```

In the above conditional statement you are saying, if the browser is less than(lt) IE 8, then display this.

Comment: is there perhaps something wrong with how im opening the file then? I simply save as an html file and open with IE, so i expect it to execute the comments that are like <!--[if (IE)]>       i am IE <![endif]-->, but instead it actually executes the comments that say <!--[if !(IE)]><!--> i am not ie <!--<![endif]-->

Comment: Ya, there must be something wrong with your code, because code written in Notepad will work exactly the same as code written in any other text editor. I've added what a conditional IE statement should look like to my answer.

Comment: I see, it seems like the problem I am having is that it is not treating my internet explorer as IE, but i have no idea why.

Comment: The code I posted is to only show for IE, if you want to display something on all browsers EXCEPT for IE you would need to place it within these tags: `<!--[if !IE]--><!--[endif]-->`

Comment: yeah i get that, right now no matter what browser i use (IE included) i am only able to see the !(IE) tags and for whatever reason when i try with jfiddle it shows BOTH (IE) and !(IE) tags

Comment: There shouldn't be any parentheses around `IE`

Comment: yeah I used the proper tags i just tried to simplify it a bit for convenience